# PostgreSQL create tablespace no permission

Tags: database, postgresql

I've got a problem when I create tablespace for PostgreSQL.  The following are the steps:

1. `mkdir /postgres`
2. `chown postgres.postgres /postgres`
3. `su - postgres`
4. `psql`
5. `create tablespace p1 location '/postgres'`

In this step I got a error:

```
could not set permissions on directory "/postgres": Permission denied
```

The directory ownership is correct:

```
[root@dev ~]# ls -la /postgres  
总用量 8  
drwxr-xr-x.  2 postgres postgres 4096 12月  2 13:17 . 
dr-xr-xr-x. 28 root     root     4096 12月  3 06:57 ..
```

the user is `postgres`

```
[root@dev contrib]# ps -ef|grep postgres  
postgres  1971     1  0 08:21 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/data
```

I'm running on CentOS.

fix: 
setenforce 0

Comment: Could you paste the output of `ls -la /postgres`?

Comment: thank you for help [root@dev data]# ls -la /postgres
总用量 8
drwxr-xr-x.  2 postgres postgres 4096 12月  2 13:17 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 28 root     root     4096 12月  2 13:17 ..

Comment: Please append the listing to the question - right now it's illegible.

Comment: `ls -dZ /postgresql`, `ls -dZ /var/lib/pgsql/9.3` (or whatever your Pg version is) and `ps Z -u postgres` please. Also, **always** include your PostgreSQL version and OS in all questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a wild guess I'd say you're on Mac OS X and your PostgreSQL is running as the user `postgres_` (note the underscore), as is used by some PostgreSQL packages.

`ps -ef | grep postgres` or `ps aux|grep postgres` should show you what user the server is running as. Make sure the directory is owned by that user.

**Update** based on extra info in comments:

You're on CentOS, not Mac OS X. Your PostgreSQL is running as user `postgres`, which is the same owner as the directory. It thus seems likely that you are having issues with *SELinux*. If, *for testing purposes only*, you run:

```
setenforce 0
```

are you then able to run the `CREATE TABLESPACE` command? (`DROP` the tablespace after creating it with SELinux temporarily off; if you don't, and restart, PostgreSQL will fail to start up).

If creation fails with SELinux temporarily disabled, you must either exempt PostgreSQL from your SELinux policy, create the tablespace at a location that the SELinux policy permits, or set appropriate SELinux attributes on the tablespace directory so that PostgreSQL can manipulate it. Or you can turn SELinux off entirely, but that's not really preferable.

There might be hints in dmesg, or in CentOS's SELinux helper tool, to tell you specific SELinux booleans you can turn on or off to control this. See the help for the `setsebool` command, the [Fedora Security Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/index.html), the [CentOS SELinux howto](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux), etc.

Perhaps the best option is to just change the SELinux context of the file. See [the documentation](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html). You can use `chcon`, but then the change will be lost after a file system relabel. It's better to use `semanage` as discussed in the next page of the linked manual.

Comment: i'm on centos.i've checked it.the user is postgres.follow is the result.

Comment: [root@dev contrib]# ps -ef|grep postgres
postgres  1971     1  0 08:21 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/data

Comment: @9ban Updated based on comments. Always include this kind of info - OS and version, PostgreSQL version and install method, etc - in your original question.

Comment: as you say.when i setenforce 0 .it's ok.then restart.postgresql start up success thank

Comment: @9ban OK, so that confirms it's SELinux. That is *not a permanent solution* though. It'll just go back when you reboot. Turn off the targeted SELinux policy for PostgreSQL, or relabel the `/postgresql/` mount point correctly as `system_u:object_r:postgresql_db_t:s0` so Pg is allowed to access it.